# Fine (CSS) granularity on HTML table cells exported via Emacs/Org Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, ergonomics

I am trying to gain finer programmatic (Emacs Lisp) control over a set of tables exported from Emacs' Org Mode to HTML.  [This task is part of an alternative approach to that taken by the [ErgoEmacs](http://mlf176f2.github.io/ErgoEmacs/#sec-2) community where SVG is used to convert text files to a PNG file that illustrates alternative ergonomic layouts for using Emacs.]
Briefly, the tables are an abstraction of an Apple BlueTooth Keyboard where each Emacs/Org Mode table represents a row of keyboard keys, thus there are six tables with 12 to 14 keys (columns) per row.

Within Emacs, in the org-mode buffer, my abstraction is rendered perfectly using the org mode meta row to specify the size of each column: `| / | <c12> | <c7> | <c7> | ...`

The generated Org Mode output within Emacs is both accurate and powerful.  On export to HTML, using CSS, the best I've been able to do (Org Mode is version 7, btw) is to fix the width of every cell to an identical value which yields a grossly inaccurate rendering.  I am trying to figure out a way (using CSS or something else that preserves the Emacs buffer rendering) to assign individual cell widths or individual column widths for the exported HTML.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If what fniessen suggested isn't enough, you can use `:custom_id: special-table` property to assign it to the table in question and then put the CSS definitions in a `#special-table { ... }` class.

But, actually, `org-mode` already creates some ids (it derives them from section numbers), so you could always reach to the table you are interested in via something like `#section-id table:nth-child(x) { ... }` rule.

If you want to generate CSS rules dynamically, then one way of doing that would be to have an `org-babel` block of code that renders the results using `:results html` on that block. for example, something like this would work:

```
#+NAME: insert-css
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none :var nth-child=1
   (print
    (format
     "<style type=\"text/css\">
       #section table:nth-child(%s) { color: orange }
      </style>" nth-child))
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: insert-css(nth-child=3) :results html

The code above produces this output:
# <style type="text/css">
#     #section table:nth-child(3) { color: orange }
#    </style>
```

However, there's one minor disadvantage of the later approach: even though all browsers understand `<style>` tags in the body of the HTML document, technically, it's not valid to put it there. Of course, if you were super-pedantic, you could have a JavaScript function inserting CSS at run time at a more proper location, but I think it would be an overkill for the task.

Comment: This approach has some potential since it leverages the section id, something I should have thought of.  I think the proper thing to do is to have the elisp code generate the external CSS file.  Well worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could (try to) reach your goal by adding a #+ATTR_HTML line in front of your table. There, you should insert CSS specs. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You are not mistaken only if you know that this particular attribute can be written to say something like column 1 is width 9em, column 2 through 14 are width 7em, etc.  I don't see how to do that from the ATTR_HTML entity.